# Python regex matchs not all characters wanted

Tags: python, regex

I have some txt-files made from pdfs and want so add some xml-tags using a little python-script and regex-patterns. Mostly it works fine but sometimes an expression matches not all the characters wanted. In the testing tool [here](https://regex101.com/#python) it works right.

Here's the python-code:

```
matchs = re.finditer("<UTop>[^<]+",string)
    for m in matchs:
        tagend = m.end()
        string = string[:tagend] + "</UTop>" + string[tagend:]
```

The original string...

```
<Top>1. Regierungserklärung des Ministerpräsidenten<UTop>Ministerpräsident Winfried Kretschmann </Top>
```

... should be transformed to:

```
<Top>1. Regierungserklärung des Ministerpräsidenten<UTop>Ministerpräsident Winfried Kretschmann </UTop></Top>
```

but it returns

```
<Top>1. Regierungserklärung des Ministerpräsidenten<UTop>Ministerpräsident Winfried Krets</UTop>chmann </Top>
```

instead.

I would be glad to get a reply to that question.
Jan

Comment: In case you are trying to parse HTML with regex, [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4464702)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test it using [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and the result seems to be right.

```
 #coding: utf-8
 import re
 input = "<Top>1. Regierungserklärung des Ministerpräsidenten<UTop>Ministerpräsident Winfried Kretschmann </Top>"
 print(re.sub(r"(<UTop>[^<]+)","\g<1><\\UTop>" ,input))
```

As you said regex testing tools works properly too. [here](https://regex101.com/r/eX1fN2/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use the Unicode flag:

```
matchs = re.finditer("<UTop>[^<]+",string,re.UNICODE)
```

For HTML consider using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) instead.

Comment: +1 for BeautifulSoup. See also [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) for details regarding the handling of broken HTML input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately unicode flags didn't solve the problem.